# How to force flex children not to overflow the container?

Tags: css, flexbox

Given a flexbox container, how could I make sure that, if children have lots of content, they don't overflow the container?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 210px;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}
.first {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.second {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.third {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">first first first first first first first</div>
  <div class="second child">second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second</div>
  <div class="third child">third</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you want the overflowing content to go? Hide it? https://jsfiddle.net/8g7p4mkt/

Comment: I'd like to have a scrollbar when content doesn't fit.

Comment: Where do you want the scrollbar...on the container or the content?

Comment: The scrollbar should be on the "second" content in the first Bad example, and on the "third" content in the second Bad example.

Comment: Then apply `overflow: auto` to the container (for one scrollbar) or the items (for scrollbars on each). I posted an answer with an example.

Comment: Seems to me you have too many competing requirements. completely flexible children with no set height but then expect them to apply scrollbars without setting a height. Pretty sure that this is not posisble to meet every eventuality...at least in flexbox.

Comment: Would adding *overflow-y: scroll;* to the child class work for you?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The children overflow their parent element because their intrinsic height (the height of their contents) is larger than the parent's height. You can advise the browser to ignore the intrinsic height by setting `min-height: 0` on the child elements. If you add `overflow: hidden` the result should be what you seem to expect:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 210px;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.first {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.second {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.third {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">first first first first first first first</div>
  <div class="second child">second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second</div>
  <div class="third child">third</div>
</div>
```

The children get height distributed among them proportionally to their content height. Overflowing content is hidden.

Comment: I get that the height is proportionally distributed, but I'd like the first and the third child (in this case) to be fully visible.

Comment: But, yeah, in general case, it's not clear what should be visible and what should get a scrollbar, so I guess your solution is as close as we can get here.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko: Yes, "make visible whatever can be fully visible and hide overflow on the rest" isn't doable with CSS. Already because it is ambiguous: what if both first and third could be fully visible on their own but not together?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `min-height: 0`. It isn't needed and you can remove it from the example. only the `overflow` matters here and will limit the children from overflowing the flex parent

Answer (score 0):

flex has
Three values: flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis;

you should apply particular max-height for first child.

```css
.first {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex: 0 1 1;
  max-height:70px;
}
```

otherwise if first div height increases it will dominate on other divs.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 210px;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;

}
.first {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
.second {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
  flex: 0 1 1;
}
.third {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
 flex: 0 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">first first first first first first first</div>
  <div class="second child">second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second</div>
  <div class="third child">third</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `overflow: auto` on `child` element. In case you want to hide `overflow` only on largest item then you could use `flex: 1` on that item.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 210px;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.first {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.second {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
  flex: 1;
}
.third {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first child">first first first first first first first</div>
  <div class="second child">second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second second</div>
  <div class="third child">third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't which item is the largest. It's completely dynamic.

Answer (score -2):

Using `min-height: 210px;` instead of explicitly setting a height on your container gives you the desired affect by letting an extra long child to extend its height.

Also, great question writing! Nice to see diagrams of whats happening vs expected, ect.