# Fitting image into flex-direction: column - explanation and fixes?

Tags: css, flexbox

The task is to fit `<img>` with text blocks above and below it into container with specified height.

The height of the text blocks and of image is undetermined.

After several hours of searching and discussing the problem my colleague helped me with working hack `height: 100%;` on flexbox child containing the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/d9kd9k/j0bxvLus/14/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container .cell-image {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.container .cell-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell cell-top">
    text 1
  </div>

  <div class="cell cell-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x800" />
  </div>

  <div class="cell cell-bottom">
    text 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please explain why it's working?

And why does flexbox work without "100%" hack for `flex-direction: row` with limited container width?

Comment: it's not a hack and it's not working correclty .. you will notice that you have an overflow because the container of the image will get 300px height (the one of its parent) and the text will overflow

Comment: for the row direction, it works because the default alignment is strectch so it's forcing the height to be 100% (change `align-items` to notice this)

Comment: Also there is something important in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351775/1760643: "The children overflow their parent element because their intrinsic height (the height of their contents) is larger than the parent's height. You can advise the browser to ignore the intrinsic height by setting min-height: 0 on the child elements.", but I couldn't make the hack "min-height: 0" work properly

Comment: applying min-height should work on the container of the image which is the *child* of the flexbox container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think without using height 100% using `flex:1` and `overflow:auto` is the best choice.and limiting image's height 100%.

```css
.container .cell-image {
   display: flex;
   flex: 1;
   overflow: auto;
}
.container .cell-image img {
   height:100%
}
```

Comment: looks better. also `object-fit: contain;` for img (try wide image instead of tall). Also now I it can work with `max-height` instead of `height` which is perfect for me :) see: https://jsfiddle.net/d9kd9k/j0bxvLus/22/

Comment: Yea, you can do anything on the image you prefer inside the container.