# Can't overflow: scroll internal div in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to prevent a flexbox child from overflowing it's container, but using overflow:auto on a child div doesn't seem to work.

My basic setup: I have a flexbox container with 2 divs, A and B. The A div has 2 internal divs, A1 and A2, and the B div only has one internal div B1. I'm trying to keep A1 and B1 static, and show a scrollbar on A2 when it overflows.

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="A1">A1</div>
    <div class="A2">A2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="B"><div class="B1">B1</div></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  Height: 400px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: gray;
}

.A {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1, 1, auto;
}

.B {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0, 0, auto;
}

.A1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0, 0, auto;
}

.A2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1, 1, auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 800px;
}

.B1 {
    background-color: blue;
  flex: 0, 0, auto;
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lzDL.png)

Here's a code example:
https://codepen.io/guybarn/pen/QWvWVMb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want scroll `A2` then it should be `A2` which is overflowed. But in your case you are overflowing `.wrap`. As you set `A2 as height:800px;` and `A as flex:0, 0, auto;` ,so your `A class div` expand which as a result overflows your `.wrap which is height:400px;`.

So what you need is to set a fixed height and add `overflow-y:scroll` for `A2` where height should be compatible with height of wrap so it does not get overflowed and add scrollbar to your `A2` when your content inside A2 gets overflowed. Following should better represent your what you need:

**Edit:** Since i misunderstood the question, so here is edit with better solution.
As I already mentioned that overflow is result of height of children more than than the parent container. In this particular case as `A2` has height which overflow its parent `A` which in result overflows `.wrap`.

***Solution is min-height: 0;*** (or some actual value). We add this to flex children Otherwise the flex child containing the other elements won’t narrow past the “implied height” of those elements.

So all we have to do is to set `min-height:0` (or some other value) to `A.` And set `min-height:0` (or some other value) and `overflow-y:scroll;` to class A2. Here if you need more [info](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/) or [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325987/how-to-force-flex-children-not-to-overflow-the-container) example.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: gray;
  }

.A {
  min-height:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1, 1, auto;
}

.B {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0, 0, auto;
}

.A1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0, 0, auto;
}

.A2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  min-height:0;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.B1 {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 0, 0, auto;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="A1">
      <div>A1</div>
      <div>A1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="A2">
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
      <div>A2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    <div class="B1">
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>B1</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the solution and it makes sense, but my issue is that I don't know the height of A2, since B1 is also slightly dynamic according to the screen dimensions. I'd like A1 and B1 to take all the space they need, and for A2 to take the remaining space.

Comment: @GuyBarner My bad I didn't understood the main point you were trying to make So I edited my answer with new solution.